# how can i use for loop to simplify this coding?

Tags: r

```
A$`Type B`=c(17 2, 9, 0, 5, 8)
A$`Type C`=c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)
```

```
p1=sum(A$`Type B`==1 & A$`Type C` ==0)
p1*1
p11=sum(A$`Type B`==1 & A$`Type C` ==1)
p11*1

p2=sum(A$`Type B`==2 & A$`Type C` ==0)
p2*2
p21=sum(A$`Type B`==2 & A$`Type C` ==1)
p21*2

p3=sum(A$`Type B`==3 & A$`Type C` ==0)
p3*3
p31=sum(A$`Type B`==3 & A$`Type C` ==1)
p31*3
...
```

how can i use for loop to simplify this coding? for (i in 1:5) A$`Type B`== [i] then p[i]1*[i]

Comment: Would you please give a little bit of explanation about your variables? `Type C` will always be either `0` or `1`?

Comment: And also it would be much better if you could share a reproducible piece of your data structure by means of `dput(head(data))`.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use a `for` loop to count the frequencies you can use the following solution:

```
# First we create an empty frequency matrix. Then we set the rownames and colnames to 
# the values they could take

result <- matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 2)
dimnames(result) <- list(c(1, 2, 3), c(0, 1))

# Then we populate the empty frequency matrix by the number of occurrence of 
# each combination

for(i in as.numeric(rownames(result))) {
  for(j in as.numeric(colnames(result))) {
    result[i, j + 1] <- sum(A$`Type B` == i & A$`Type C` == j) * i
  }
}

result

  0 1
1 3 1
2 2 2
3 0 3
```

I have created a sample data to test the for loop.

```
A <- data.frame(`Type B` = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1), 
                `Type C` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), check.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, you can try :

```
library(dplyr)
res <- A %>%  count(`Type B`, `Type C`) %>% mutate(n = n * `Type B`)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A)[, .(n = .N), .(`Type B`, `Type C`)][, n := n * `Type B`][]
```